# LWC div id coming with extra "-0" when loaded in a Salesforce Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, html, community-builder

I have run into an issue with LWC and Salesforce Communities in which the id of a specific div contains an extra "-0" at the end when loaded in the browser. The code in the lwc contains the correct div id (see below)

[image: Pushed html in LWC]

However, when the community page loads in the browser, an extra "-0" is being added to the end of the div id.

[image: Community loaded in browser]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was implementing a way for an external cookie manager to display the policy on a Salesforce community page. **Converting my cookie policy LWC into an Aura component seemed to fix this issue.** The Aura component does not add a trailing "-0" to an id attribute, so when it is loaded on the page the id is correct and the id can be found.

Answer (score 2):

explanation for this is mentioned in the lwc documenration [Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work)

> Don’t use ID selectors with querySelector. The IDs that you define in
> HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the
> template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it
> won’t match the transformed ID.

LWC framework set's unique global `id` for the element.

consider using classes for styling or custom `data-` attributes for selecting elements.

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, Thanks for your comment. The problem is, we aren't using ids for styling in this case. We are using the id so our external cookie management system can reference a place on the page to dynamically add our cookie policy. And since the id is being added with the extra "-0", it cannot find the div in which to place the policy. Should we just use an aura component instead?

Comment: @Ryllini you should consider finding other than the usage of `id` for your purpose, as again, `id` can be (or not) transformed. it applies both for lwc and aura  [Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I'll see what we can do. Not sure if it is possible for us in this case since the external cookie manager looks for the id on the page. We will try to have them reference something else.

Comment: @Ryllini Have you figured a solution ? I have exactly the same issue, I need to integrate an external cookie setup

Comment: @AshBringer - We converted our LWC for the cookie policy into an Aura component. The Aura component does not add a trailing "-0" at the end of an id attribute.

Comment: @Ryllini Thanks! I did the same thing :(, fortunately I was on a small component